# Adding a 0 before decimal entered in input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to finish up a quick form using jQuery that needs to add a 0 before a decimal point if the decimal is the first char entered in the input.

For example,
.25 would become 0.25 before the form is submitted.
However, 2.05 would stay as 2.05, and no 0 would be added.

Is there a simple function here that could help me out? I'd rather not write something long and detailed if it's not necessary.

Also, here is the input box that I am asking for help with, for reference

```
<input type="number" name="dailygain" id="dailygain" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) function to format float numbers.

```
var el = document.getElementById("dailygain");
el.value = parseFloat(el.value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 1 (`*1`) to make it numeric.

If you make it a number, it'll do it for you automatically; formatting based on your systems locale.

Example:

```
var x = '.25';
console.log( x*1 );  // 0.25
```

The same can be accomplished with a unary plus (e.g., `console.log( +x );` )

Comment: While it does add the leading 0 on normal web browsers, when using a mobile browser on my Android phone, if I leave off the leading 0 the entered input just disappears. I have no idea why that would be the default behavior.

Comment: Very interesting.  I've never heard that.  If going from string to numeric doesn't exist on Android phones, then there's a bigger problem going on.  JavaScript was set up to make transitioning between string and numerics easy from the beginning.  You should be able to multiply a numeric-string by a number to get a number.

Answer (score 0):

parseFloat is probably more suited, but anyway :

```
$('#dailygain').on('keyup', function() {
    if (this.value[0] === '.') this.value = '0'+this.value;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/bTPxp/)
​

Answer (score 0):

Put this in a function run `onsubmit`.

```
var num=$("#dailygain").val(); //read the number from the textbox
num=num.toString(); //convert that number to a string
if (num.charAt(0)==".") //check if the string starts with a period
    num="0"+num; //if so, add a 0 in front of it
$("#dailygain").val(num); //write the number back to the tb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name=dailygain]").keyup(function(){
   var val = this.value;
   if(val.charAt(0) === '.'){
     this.value = ('0'+val); 
   }
});
```

http://jsbin.com/ofivun/2/edit